# Callback failed Error for Lightning Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-experience, javascript-controller, javascript-debugging

I am facing the below error for the Lightning component. I tried to debug but was not able to find the root cause.

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
> Error in $A.getCallback() [ErrorAn internal server error has occurred
> Error ID: 1410665541-125747 (-429116149)]
> Callback failed: apex://CarSearchController/ACTION$getCars
> Failing descriptor: {markup://c:Base}

Following is the code:
CarSearchResult.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" extends="c:Base" access="global" controller="CarSearchController">
    <aura:attribute type="Car__c[]" name="cars" access="public"/>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="carTypeId" access="private" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute type="boolean" name="carFound" access="private" default="false"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" horizontalAlign="center">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.carFound}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.cars}" var="car">
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" 
                                      size="12" 
                                      smallDeviceSize="6" 
                                      mediumDeviceSize="4" 
                                      largeDeviceSize="3">
                    {!car.Name}
                </lightning:layoutItem> 
            </aura:iteration>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    No Cars Found
                </div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
        
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

CarSearchResultHelper.js

```
({
    onSearch : function(component,helper) {
        console.log('before helper');
        debugger;
        helper.callServer(component,"c.getCars",
                          function(response){
                              console.log('in response function');
                              if(response.length > 0){
                                  console.log('in helper');
                                  component.set("v.cars",response);
                                  component.set("v.carFound",true);
                              }else{
                                  component.set("v.carFound",false);
                              }
                          },{
                              carTypeId:'a0R7F00000iqPDsUAM'
                          });
        
    }
})
```

BaseHelper.js

```
({
    callServer : function(component,method,callback,params ) {
        console.log('in base helper'+params);
        var action = component.get(method);
        if(params){
            action.setParams(params);
        }
        console.log('in base helper action'+action);
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                callback.call(this,response.getReturnValue());
            }else if(state === "ERROR"){
                var error = response.getError();
                if(error){
                    console.log("Errors"+error);
                    if(error[0] && error[0].message){
                        throw new Error("Error"+ error[0].message);
                    }
                }else{
                   throw new Error("Unknown Error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

CarSearchController class

```
public with sharing class CarSearchController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Car__c> getCars(String carTypeId){
        if(carTypeId.equalsIgnoreCase('')){
            return[SELECT Id, Name, Build_Year__c, Car_Type__c, Contact__r.Name, Description__c,
                   Geolocation__Latitude__s, Geolocation__Longitude__s,
                   Geolocation__c, Mileage__c, Per_Day_Rent__c, Picture__c FROM Car__c where Available_For_Rent__c = true];
        }else{
            return[SELECT Id, Name, Build_Year__c, Car_Type__c, Contact__r.Name, Description__c,
                   Geolocation__Latitude__s, Geolocation__Longitude__s,
                   Geolocation__c, Mileage__c, Per_Day_Rent__c, Picture__c FROM Car__c where Available_For_Rent__c = true AND 
                   Car_Type__c = :carTypeId];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As such there is no issue in the posted source code. Have you tried making the apex call directly from `CarSearchResult` component and check if the issue persists? Have you checked permission related possibilities (such as the access to the apex class for the profile of the user who is executing the code)? Or version mismatch?

Comment: -I checked for the permissions of the class, the user has the permission.

Comment: I am new to lightning development, is there any way to debug the above component where I will get the exact line number of the code where error is occurring like apex

Comment: Is it possible that your result set is very large? I had the same issue when loading a large dataset. You can potentially debug this by (1) reducing the amount of queried fields or (2) to return a JSON.serialize-d version of your data to see if the data is then correctly transferred to your aura component. If one or both of these techniques work, consider reducing the amount of data fetched in one call.

Comment: @voluminat0 - I tried the first part, it didn't work. can you guide me more for the second solution that you have given.

Comment: @AdityaPhadke there is a method in apex called JSON.serialize(object) (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm). In your case, you can try to apply this to the List<Car__c>. Then, you can check if any data is passed to your aura component. If this is the case, then something might go wrong during transfer of the List<Car__c>, as in your original post.